# Odd grid sizing behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been using tkinter's `grid` geometry manager and have configured all the rows and columns to `weight = 1`. The problem comes when I try to resize a `Tk()` window. When I resize it vertically only, the width of widgets and the proportion of column widths also change despite their equal `weight`. Furthermore, the width of the columns isn't in the desired proportions (i.e. all equal) before doing any resizing - to be precise the first column (with labels and buttons) is as wide as other two (holding a canvas with `columnspan = 2` and two labels).

I think the problem is somehow connected to the `PiSimulator._adjust_sizes` function which dynamically changes the font or to the use of the canvas with a `columnspan` of 2.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font    

class PiSimulator(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        super(PiSimulator, self).__init__(root, **kwargs)
        self.root = root
        self.root.title = 'Crtac krugova'
        self.root.minsize(width = 600, height = 400)
        self.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)
        self.custom_font = font.Font(size = 20)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self._adjust_sizes)
        self.populate()
        return

    def populate(self):

        tk.Label(self, text = 'Radijus:', font = self.custom_font, relief = 'raised',\
                        fg = 'green').grid(sticky='nswe', row = 0, column = 0)      
        self.radius = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Spinbox(self, from_ = 1, to = 16, font = self.custom_font, textvariable = self.radius).grid(row = 1, column = 0) 

        tk.Label(self, text = 'Greška', font = self.custom_font, relief = 'raised', anchor='w',\
                        padx = 5, pady = 5, fg = 'green').grid(sticky='nswe', row = 0, column = 1)

        self.error = tk.DoubleVar(0.0)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.error, font = self.custom_font, relief = 'raised',\
                        anchor='e', pady = 5, fg = 'green').grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky='nswe')


        self.canvas = PiCanvas(self, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.canvas.grid(row = 1, rowspan = 5, column = 1, columnspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky='nswe')

        tk.Button(self, text = 'Nacrtaj', font = self.custom_font, command = lambda: self.canvas.draw(self.radius.get())).grid(\
                        column = 0, row = 2, sticky='nswe')
        tk.Button(self, text = 'Izbriši',  font = self.custom_font, command = self.canvas.clear ).grid(\
                        column = 0, row = 3, sticky='nswe')
        tk.Label(self, text = 'POVRŠINA', relief = 'groove',  font = self.custom_font).grid(column = 0, row = 4, sticky='nswe')
        self.area = tk.IntVar(0)
        tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.area, relief = 'groove',  font = self.custom_font).grid(column = 0, row = 5, sticky='nswe')


        for i in range(3):
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight = 1)
        for i in range(6):
            self.rowconfigure(i, weight = 1)
        return

    def _adjust_sizes(self, event):
        new_font = int(event.height/15) - 2
        self.custom_font.configure(size = new_font)
        return


class PiCanvas(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, root, **kwargs):
        super(PiCanvas, self).__init__(root, background = 'white', relief = 'groove',  **kwargs)
        self.root = root
        self.cubes = []
        self.circle = None

    def draw(self, radius):
        self.clear()
        c_width = self.winfo_width()
        c_height = self.winfo_height()
        self.grid_side = int(min([c_width, c_height]))
        self.grid_side-= 10
        self.v_offset = (c_height - self.grid_side)/2
        self.h_offset = (c_width - self.grid_side)/2
        self.cube_side = self.grid_side/(2*radius)
        vertix_coord = lambda x, x_cor, y_cor: x_cor*self.h_offset+y_cor*self.v_offset+x*self.cube_side

        for i in range(2*radius):
            new_line = []
            for j in range(2*radius):
                cube = self.create_rectangle(vertix_coord(i, 1, 0), vertix_coord(j, 0, 1),\
                                                vertix_coord(i+1, 1, 0), vertix_coord(j+1, 0, 1), tag = 'unused')
                new_line.append(cube)
            self.cubes.append(new_line)

        self.circle = self.create_oval(vertix_coord(0,1,0), vertix_coord(0,0,1),\
                                    vertix_coord(2*radius,1,0), vertix_coord(2*radius,0,1),width = 2)
        self.color_border_cubes()
        print(self.circle)

    def color_border_cubes(self):
        circle_coords = self.coords(self.circle)
        print(circle_coords)
        for i in self.cubes:
            for j in i:
                cube_coords = self.coords(j)
                if self.circle in self.find_overlapping(*cube_coords) + self.find_enclosed(*circle_coords):
                    self.itemconfigure(j, fill = 'green')


    def clear(self):
        self.cubes = []
        self.circle = None
        self.delete('all')      
        return


root = tk.Tk()
a=PiSimulator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does the following help answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21002617/7432, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21009232/7432

Comment: Ouch, how did I miss that question? Thanks, that's what I needed, but i still don't understand why horizontal resizing worked without this adjustment.