# Put a grid vertical line between columns in the middle of the window in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

It's a little complicated, but I'll try my best to explain:
let's say that for example, I have a grid with 4 labels when I have 2 rows and 2 columns (see image below). I'm trying to make the vertical line between columns 1 and 2 (red line in the image) to be the line that splits the window into two equal halves.
[image: image example]

You can see a sample of my initial code below.
**Edit:** note that the elements are labels just for example, but in my original code they are actually all different (some are frames, some images, some buttons, etc)

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text=1, width=8, height=2, bg="red")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text=2, width=10, height=3, bg="green")
label2.grid(row=0, column=1)

label3 = tk.Label(root, text=3, width=5, height=4, bg="blue")
label3.grid(row=1, column=0)

label4 = tk.Label(root, text=4, width=6, height=2, bg="yellow")
label4.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This code makes the vertical and horizontal center lines of each label perfect as I wanted, but the vertical line between columns 1 and 2 (red line in image) is nowhere near to be the center of the window.

[image: running the code]

Then, I have tried adding the `grid_columnconfigure` function to my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # the line I've added

label1 = tk.Label(root, text=1, width=8, height=2, bg="red")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text=2, width=10, height=3, bg="green")
label2.grid(row=0, column=1)

label3 = tk.Label(root, text=3, width=5, height=4, bg="blue")
label3.grid(row=1, column=0)

label4 = tk.Label(root, text=4, width=6, height=2, bg="yellow")
label4.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

But now I have a different problem, where the columns don't touch each other.

[image: running code with changes]

I've also tried to fix the issue by adding the `sticky` arguments when I'm placing the elements in the grid, and also tried putting every row and every column in their own frame, but all of the solutions did not work out for me.
How can I get this to work? Hope my explanation was clear, and thanks in advance (;

Answer (score 1):

You could just put the four images/labels together into a `Frame` (or any other container element) and then have that frame horizontally and vertically centered in your `root` frame with [`place`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).

```
c = tk.Frame(root, bg='white')
c.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
```

Don't forget to change the parent of the labels from `root` to `c`, i.e. `Label(c, ...)`.

Update: But this does not center the line between the red and the green block to the frame. You could combine this with [`uniform`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21006752/1639625) to make the columns equal width, but then there will be some padding between the center and the thinner column...

```
for n in (0, 1):
    c.grid_columnconfigure(n, uniform="foo")
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that in my post I have wanted the vertical line between column 1 and 2 to be in the center of the window. With this solution, you take the whole grid and position it at the center of the window. I've tried to explain it using [this image.](https://i.imgur.com/fJ4PLJT.png)

Comment: @RealA10N Getting closer, I guess, but still not exactly as you want it. Would inspecting the images and adding some columns for padding be an option?

Comment: What do you mean by "inspecting"? I want this prosses to be automated, and not hardcoded. Also note that the elements are images just for example, but in my original code they are actually all different (some are frames, some images, some buttons, etc)

Comment: @RealA10N Sure, the idea was that if those are images, you could read the width and height and insert padding accordingly. If those can be any widgets, than this might not be possible (or not that easy), as their size is only determined at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ttk.Separator widget.
You should use the following code part:

```
import tkinter.ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

---etc---
---etc---
---etc---

tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=2, sticky='ns')

root.mainloop()
```

You can get the grid info of a widget with "grid_info" method.

```
row    = widget.grid_info()['row']      # Row of the widget
column = widget.grid_info()['column']   # Column of the widget
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I'm not trying to add a line between the columns (;

Answer (score 0):

Since there are 2 columns, `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` only affects the first column.
Try

```py
for n in range(2):
    root.grid_columnconfigure(n, weight=1)
```

or

```py
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Comment: Still, there are spaces between the columns - something that I want to avoid.